# Stop NSSwitch on first match

Tags: nss

I am using a MySQL backend to store some of my UNIX users into a database. In order for the system to be able to retrieve name information about these users, I added MySQL to NSS's sources:

```
passwd:         files mysql
group:          files mysql
shadow:         files mysql
```

However, when I request information about a user stored in `/etc/passwd` ("`files`" source), the MySQL backend is still queried (I can see the query I configured in `/etc/libnss-mysql.cfg` being executed).

Is there anyway I could have NSS stop after a match, so that MySQL isn't queried when the user/group is found using the typical UNIX authentication resources?

**As you'll see in Edit 2, my problem appears when NSS tries to build the groups list, not when it looks up a specific name. This may be why the default `SUCCESS` => `return` chain isn't applied here.**

*Edit:* I tried "forcing" NSS to return on first match using the following...

```
passwd:         files [SUCCESS=return] mysql
group:          files [SUCCESS=return] mysql
shadow:         files [SUCCESS=return] mysql
```

(despite the fact that [`return` is supposed to be the default for the `SUCCESS` status](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html)), but MySQL is still queried. Removing `mysql` from the lines does restrict NSS to the files, so we can clearly say that even on `SUCCESS`, NSS `continue`s.

*Edit 2 (how I can see that MySQL is still queried)* : my MySQL queries are such that when MySQL is queried, no matter what username you're querying about, the groups list returned will always contain GID 5000. So, for instance, if `myuser` (stored in the DB) belongs to `mygroup` (also stored in the DB), then MySQL will return both `mygroup` and GID 5000. Schematically, there is what you can observe:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM grouplist WHERE username='myuser';
|---------------------------|
| GID           |  USERNAME |
|---------------------------|
| n             |  myuser   |
|---------------------------|

$ id myuser
uid=m(myuser) gid=n(mygroup) groups=n(mygroup),5000(forcedgroup)

                                                      ^^^^
                                            added for every SQL query
```

This little "addition" is made by the query itself:

```
gidsbymem   SELECT id FROM ( \
                SELECT id FROM grouplist WHERE username='%1$s' \
                UNION SELECT 5000 AS id \
            ) AS custom_groups
```

Now, when I request information about a user stored in `/etc/passwd` with `id myotheruser`, I can see GID 5000 in his groups, despite the fact that there is no such association in `/etc/group`. To me, what happens is that:

- NSS reads `/etc/passwd` and finds `myotheruser`.
- NSS queries my DB, does not find the user, but still returns GID 5000 as a group list.
- `myotheruser`, who does not belong to any SQL group, has GID 5000 in its groups list, since MySQL added it.

Schematically:

```
$ id myotheruser
uid=n(myotheruser) gid=n(myothergroup) groups=n(myothergroup),5000(forcedgroup)
```

While I would expect:

```
$ id myotheruser
uid=n(myotheruser) gid=n(myothergroup) groups=n(myothergroup)
```

However, when I remove MySQL from NSS's sources, `myotheruser` no longer has GID 5000 in his list (which is why I can say that MySQL is the one adding it).

Comment: That's not expected behaviour. My experience (and the man page for nsswitch.conf) says that lookup terminates after successful match. Could nscd be confusing things? Perhaps (assuming this isn't a production server) turning ncsd off would clarify things.

Comment: @PaulHaldane Since I'm still testing my configurations, I haven't installed `nscd` yet (in order to prevent such problems from occuring while I'm setting the system up).

Comment: Ah! When initialising a user's set of groups I would expect all backends to be used (because you're scanning a list rather than looking up a value). Perhaps the initgroups database in addition to group might help. I hadn't come across that until I read man page earlier.

Comment: I don't quite see how I could use the `initgroups` database here... No matter what I try, it's all or nothing: either everyone gets GID 5000, or no one does.